# Android project: gradle configure fails

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, configure

I am trying to create a new project but the build fails and I can't solve it, can anyone tell me what was wrong in below picture
[image: this picture]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hossein.myshgop"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
} dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Comment: Please share the content of your build.gradle files

Comment: what is the build error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with the internet connection in your PC. Please check internet connection. `Gradle` requires proper internet connection.

Comment: I check internet connection it's work correctly, but still build failed

Comment: also please share your project level build.gradle

Comment: Sorry my friend I'm a starter and don't know mean the project level build.gradle. can you tell me how can I do this?